# How to start my own IT Company - What Kind of Plans and Exposure do I need to seek?

Tags: freelance, startups, company-management

I have planned to start my IT development Company based on Salesforce development not now. But, After 3 years! I need some roadmap of suggestions, exposure, and plans to seed myself to prepare me for the Startup. Kindly, I would like to receive any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

The most important aspect of starting a business is getting clients. How to do that depends on where you are (your location), what type of clients you want, and your own capabilities.

For example, if you are in a major city, then potential clients are all around you. Create a brochure and start walking the business district handing it to the receptionist. I know one person who built a business that way.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for the suggestion. I have **noted down your point** and will try to implement it when I start!